# Postgres indexing hangs indefinitely

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a GIN index on a jsonb column, no other operations are currently happening on this table(none at all). The table is about 3million rows, at about 10gb. I've tried 3 times, once for 3 days(over the weekend), and the next 2 times for several hours. It hangs indefinitely. The last 2 times I looked at the index size, each time the index stops around 290mb both times. The operation never succeeds or fails, just hangs for several hours. The CPU usage remains consistently around 1%, the memory usage barely budges, the IO remains pretty low also. I tried to VACUUM the database, I have the same issue, it just hangs indefinitely.

Queries are slow, sometimes they just timeout. I have no idea what is wrong.

The server itself isn't starving for resources, it has 2 cpus and 4GB of RAM.

Comment: If DDL statements seem to hang, they are probably waiting for a lock. Check `pg_stat_activity` from a different session to see if your `create index` is waiting.

Comment: state: active
waiting: false
Like I was saying, there are no operations running on this table, and the second attempt nothing else was even connected to the database.

Comment: The main tuning knob for index creation is `maintenance_work_mem`. That said, the low I/O and CPU usage looks fishy. Do you get any suspicious messages in the PostgreSQL log? It feels like it might be data curruption. If you create a copy of the table with `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT * FROM ...`, does indexing that second table succeed?

Comment: So suspicious logs. We are using RDS. We upgraded to 9.6(from 9.5), and now the CPU and memory both increased as well as IO. I scaled the instance to have 16GB of memory, and changed `maintenance_work_mem` to 2GB. Still nothing.

Comment: We created a new table, applied the index, and then copied that data into the new table. That hung as well, ran for nearly 24hours.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Any ideas what you do if it is due to data corruption? (and there is no recent backup)

Comment: If it is data corruption, you are lost without a backup. But follow other theories first. Try to find the resource that is bottlenecked. With a hosted database, that might be IOPS.